# How to create a shrinking world border in Minecraft

Tags: java, border, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create a shrinking world border in Minecraft with a Bukkit plugin.
Im trying to do it with a scheduler so it shrinks every second 1 or 2 blocks.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: share what you have done till now, share your source code and some one will help you

Comment: Im currently not at home so I cant share any code :(

Comment: I wanna do it with a scheduler. So it shrinks every second 1 or 2 blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the World Border.setSize(double, long) method. 
For more information, see: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/WorldBorder.html#setSize(double,%20long)